# How should test methods be named in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm learning how to test in PHPUnit and I'm wondering I want to know if there is a "best practice" when it comes to naming PHPUnit test methods. Should they just be named the same as the method being tested? For example should this method

```
getView()
```

be named

```
testGetView()
```

or should the name be more descriptive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unit test usually has a method under test (getView), a context (invalid view) and an expected outcome (errors out).

I like to separate these three with underscore and use camel case as a word separator.
e.g. testGetView_InvalidView_ErrorsOut

Most people just use camelcase to separate everything
e.g. testGetViewInvalidViewErrorsOut

As long as you are consistent with yourself, you should be fine, though.